# Class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

)

Please have a look at the code below:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myName;

    public string MyName
    {
        get { return _myName; }
        set
        {
            if (_myName != value)
            {
                _myName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyName");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Object of this class is used as a DataContext for textBox control on WPF form.

Idea is simple: changes done to MyName property of this object should be automatically displayed in textBox. It works but I do not understand why.

Please follow my way of thinking and point out where I get it wrong...

We set a new value for MyName. Program goes to 'setter' and it calls 'OnPropertyChanged'. It goes to 'OnPropertyChanged' and checks if 'PropertyChanged' is null.

And it is not. And I do not know why since I do not add any event handlers to this event.

So... how does it work?

Thank you!

Comment: you should ideally change         if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); to     var handler =PropertyChanged;   if (handler != null)
            handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); as if the propertychanged handler is changed between the if check and the call then you get a null ref exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event Handler is added automatically when you bind the object to the DataContext.

Comment: I noticed that if MyClass does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then it does not work as wanted. What is the deeper meaning of implementing this interface here?

Comment: @JacekWojcik - By implementing the interface, you indicate to WPF that you are responsible for notifying the framework when something changes and a field on your object needs to be re-rendered. If you don't implement the interface, you make no such promise to WPF and it tries to do something itself.